# How to improve efficiency

Tags: java, coding-efficiency

Write a function:

```
class Solution{
    public int solution(int[] A);   
}
```

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer(greater than 0)
that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1,3,6,4,1,2], the function should return 5.

Given A = [1,2,3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [-1, -3], the function should return 1.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions.

- N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
- each element of array A is an integer within the range [-1,000,000..1,000,000].

I wrote the following algorithm in Java:

```
public class TestCodility {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a[] = {1,3,6,4,1,2};
            //int a[] = {1,2,3};
        //int b[] = {-1,-3};
        int element = 0;
        //checks if the array "a" was traversed until the last position
        int countArrayLenght = 0;
        loopExtern:
        for(int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++){
            element = i + 1;
            countArrayLenght = 0;
            loopIntern:
            for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
                if(element == a[j]){                    
                    break loopIntern;
                }
                countArrayLenght++;
            }
            if(countArrayLenght == a.length && element > 0){
                System.out.println("Smallest possible " + element);
                break loopExtern;
            }           
        }               
    }

}
```

It does the job but I am pretty sure that it is not efficient. So my question is, how to improve this algorithm so that it becomes efficient?

Comment: "I am pretty sure that it is not efficient" <-- Why do you say that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code functions correctly, but is better-suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179037/given-an-array-of-integers-return-the-smallest-positive-integer-not-in-it

Comment: Why don't you sort it (n*log(n))? Then It is easy.

Comment: Joe C, honestly I just have a feeling. So, why would you say that it is efficient?

Comment: Marco Luzzara, how to do this? Could you please change the algorithm and post it as you've suggested?

Answer (score 0):

You should get a grasp on Big O, and runtime complexities.
Its a universal construct for better understanding the implementation of efficiency in code.

Check this website out, it shows the graph for runtime complexities in terms of Big O which can aid you in your search for more efficient programming.

http://bigocheatsheet.com/

However, long story short...
The least amount of operations and memory consumed by an arbitrary program is the most efficient way to achieve something you set out to do with your code.

You can make something more efficient by reducing redundancy in your algorithms and getting rid of any operation that does not need to occur to achieve what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Point is to sort your array and then iterate over it. With sorted array you can simply skip all negative numbers and then find minimal posible element that you need.

Here more general solution for your task:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static int solution(int[] A) {
        int result = 1;

        Arrays.sort(A);

        for(int a: A) {
            if(a > 0) {
                if(result == a) {
                    result++;
                } else if (result < a){
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a[] = {1,3,6,4,1,2};
        int b[] = {1,2,3};
        int c[] = {-1,-3};

        System.out.println("a) Smallest possible " + solution(a)); //prints 5
        System.out.println("b) Smallest possible " + solution(b)); //prints 4
        System.out.println("c) Smallest possible " + solution(c)); //prints 1
    }
}
```

Complexity of that algorithm should be O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is the same as Denis.
First sort, then process but using java8 feature.
There are few methods that may increase  timings.(not very sure how efficient java 8 process them:filter,distinct and even take-while ... in the worst case you have here something similar with 3 full loops. One additional loop is for transforming array into stream). Overall you should get the same run-time complexity.
One advantage could be on verbosity, but also need some additional knowledge compared with Denis solution.

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
public class AMin 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        int a[] = {-2,-3,1,2,3,-7,5,6}; 
        int[] i =  {1} ; 
        // get next integer starting from 1
        Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> i[0]++;

        //1. transform array into specialized int-stream
        //2. keep only positive numbers : filter
        //3. keep no duplicates : distinct
        //4. sort by natural order (ascending)
        //5. get the maximum stream based on criteria(predicate) : longest consecutive numbers starting from 1
        //6. get the number of elements from the longest "sub-stream" : count  
        long count = IntStream.of(a).filter(t->t>0).distinct().sorted().takeWhile(t->t== supplier.get()).count();

        count = (count==0) ? 1 : ++count;

        //print 4
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions with O(n) space complexity and O(n) type complexity. You can convert array to;

- set: array to set and for loop (1...N) check contains number or not. If not return number.
- hashmap: array to map and for loop (1...N) check contains number or not. If not return number.
- count array: convert given array to positive array count array like if arr[i] == 5, countArr[5]++, if arr[i] == 1, countArr[1]++ then check each item in countArr with for loop (1...N) whether greate than 1 or not. If not return it.

For now, looking more effective algoritm like @Ricola mentioned. Java solution with O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity:

```
static void swap(final int arr[], final int i,final int j){
    final int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
static boolean isIndexInSafeArea(final int arr[], final int i){
    return arr[i] > 0 && arr[i] - 1 < arr.length && arr[i] != i + 1 ;
}
static int solution(final int arr[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        while (isIndexInSafeArea(arr,i) && arr[i] != arr[arr[i] - 1]) {
            swap(arr, i, arr[i] - 1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != i + 1) {
            return i+1;
        }
    }
    return arr.length + 1;
}
```